# Retrieve data from GenBank with Bio.Entrez module

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to solve one of the Rosalind challenges and I can't seem to find a way to retrieve data, within a specific time frame.

http://rosalind.info/problems/gbk/

Do/How Do I modify Entrez.esearch() to specify a time frame?

`Question`:

`Given`: A genus name, followed by two dates in YYYY/M/D format.

`Return`: The number of Nucleotide GenBank entries for the given genus that were published between the dates specified.

Test Data:

- Anthoxanthum
- 2003/7/25
- 2005/12/27

Answer: 7

Comment: You need to figure out the exact query to give to esearch. You can do this by going to https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore, click on the 'Advanced' link right below the search box to go to the Advanced Search page. There, from the drop-down list you can select the organism and publication dates and execute your search. On the results page, you will see a 'Search details' box on the right hand side with the exact text query that was sent to the database. You can simply copy/paste that in your Entrez.esearch query function or modify to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to @Kayvee for the pointer! It works like a charm!

Here is a format for searching the organism by 'posted between start-end':

```
(Anthoxanthum[Organism]) AND ("2003/7/25"[Publication Date] : "2005/12/27"[Publication Date])
```

Here is Python code:

```
# GenBank gene database
geneName = "Anthoxanthum"
pubDateStart = "2003/7/25"
pubDateEnd = "2005/12/27"
searchTerm = f'({geneName}[Organism]) AND("{pubDateStart}"[Publication Date]: "{pubDateEnd}"[Publication Date])'

print(f"\n[GenBank gene database]:")
Entrez.email = "please@pm.me"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term=searchTerm)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
print(record["Count"])
```